# Why is KafkaTemplate losing connection to Kafka after AWS MSK cluster update?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, aws-msk

We have a Spring Boot application producing messages to a AWS MSK Kafka cluster. Every now and then our MSK cluster gets an automatic security update (or such) and after that our KafkaTemplate producer loses connection to the cluster or something so all sends end up in a timeout. The producer doesn't recover from this automatically and keeps on trying to send messages. The following idempotent sends throw an exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: The producer is not authorized to do idempotent sends
```

Restarting the producer application fixes the issue. Our producer is very simple application using KafkaTemplate to send messages without any custom retry logic or such.

One suggestion was to add a producer reset call to the error handler but testing the solution is very hard as there seems to be no real way to reproduce the issue.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/ProducerFactory.html#reset()

Any ideas why this happens and what is the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

We have an open issue to close the producer on any timeout...

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2251

Contributions are welcome.

Comment: Could this be achieved with the current KafkaTemplate for example using the producer reset method I mentioned?

Comment: Yes; see my answer on the discussion linked from that issue.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. I just wasn't sure if it applied also to this situation. I'll come back when I have more information.